# Widget is not being updated with AppWidgetManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I have a widget that updates with a button. When you click the button, the values in all fields are updated accordingly. Here is the onReceive method code:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        if(intent.action == UPDATE_BUTTON_ACTION) {
            val widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            val widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, AllServerInformationWidget::class.java))
            onUpdate(context, widgetManager, widgetIds)
        }
    }
```

The code works accordingly, but the content is updated through the onUpdate function, and not through the widgetManager function, i.e. updateAppWidget. I would like to update the content in the application itself when the user interacts with the interface, but as you can guess, nothing happens.

Here is the code snippet that should update the widgets:

```
val widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
val widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(requireContext(), AllServerInformationWidget::class.java))

if(widgetIds.isNotEmpty()) {
    val remoteViews = RemoteViews(requireContext().packageName, R.layout.all_server_information_widget)
    widgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, remoteViews)
}
```

I tried different variations of the ComponentName and RemoteViews class constructor but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The refresh button works using pendingIntent, I decided that you can also create the same instance, only call immediately after creation.

```
val intent = Intent(context, AllServerInformationWidget::class.java)
intent.action = AllServerInformationWidget.UPDATE_BUTTON_ACTION
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND // This flag is needed to eliminate button delay
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
pendingIntent.send()
```